# Transferring data from a sensor to the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an external device (some kind of sensor) that can do a measurement. This sensor can be connected to a PC via Bluetooth or USB cable, and it also comes with it's own software.
I want to develop an App for iPhone that will analyze the data that this sensor is measuring (for example creating a graph, calculating some equations etc.).
How can I make my iPhone to "recognize" this sensor, so the app will get the data that has been measured from the sensor? 
Is there any manual which explains how to code this? Our preferred way of transferring the data is via Bluetooth, so there will be no need of using cables.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Bluetooth to transfer data unless the device is custom designed in compliance with Apple's MFi program.  Only those specially manufactured devices can be recognized by an iOS app.

You can use wifi for high bandwidth data, and perhaps audio for encoding low bandwidth data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. will it possible to transfer the data to the iphone if i connect the sensor to the iphone via USB? and by the way,will it possible to do it via Bluetooth if the it's an Android smartphone..? if Android may be easier to implement i will consider to develop the app first of all to Android's phones..

Comment: USB also requires custom hardware in compliance with Apple's MFi, except perhaps for certain standardized microphone (and maybe MIDI) to USB adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of sensor you have but PASCO scientific has a Made For iPhone Bluetooth device called [AirLink2](http://store.pasco.com/pascostore/showdetl.cfm?DID=9&Product_ID=60977&Detail=1) that works with their sensors. I don't think that could easily co-opt the device for your purposes ... but it might be possible. I mention this because there's an off chance that this would useful information. I am not trying to peddle hardware here ;-)